# Android app not creating shortcut icon on home screen (downloaded from play store)

Tags: android, shortcut

After downloading app from play store, its not creating shortcut icon on home screen(it creates icon in app drawer). While this thing working fine on most of devices. But for some devices. App is not creating shortcuts.

I have checked:

a) Play store settings and Auto-Add widgets is marked.

b) Launcher settings automatically add shortcut to screen is market.

Is there anything at programmer end? Can we write some code which will result in shortcut when app downloaded from play store?

Comment: Probably a bug, however any device specifically having this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug coming from the application, it's more of a bug may be device bug probably. I'd check the caches on your device, ROM settings, etc.

Comment: I'm quite confident when I say probably not, at least not in the application you downloaded. Are you running a custom ROM? Is your phone rooted? These are key details.

Comment: Thanks I need to verify it from client end. Which device he is running and whether its rooted or not!! Most probably he is running app on S4

Answer (score 3):

[image]

There is nothing wrong with programmer ensure you have checked Add icon Home screen check box,
In some cases programmer may have written this code

`Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "AppName");
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);`

To remove short-cut which is going to be created by play store even after "Add icon to Home screen" checked. So this Solution can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Android (at least for Android 11) this option has been moved.

1. Click and hold on your home screen
2. Click on `Home Settings`  [image: home screen]
3. De-/activatie `Add app icons to the home screen | For new apps`[image: settings]

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

Go the home screen, hit apps then options (three dots at top right).

It had 'DOWNLOADED APPS' go into that then hold desired icon to create shortcut onto ur main screens.

Hope it works.