# Google Play Beta App not on Home Screen

Tags: android, google-play, beta

I have an beta version of an app in Google Play.  I've gotten beta testing to work (via a list of email addresses) but when my beta testers opt in, they are forced to return to the app store every time to open the app.  It will not allow them to place an icon on their home screen.  Is this standard for apps in the beta testing stage?  If not, any idea how I can fix it so they can open the app from their apps list like all other apps rather than returning to the play store each and every time?  Thanks!

This posted is related to, but the same as the following post (the following post refers to apps in production, my question is specifically about apps in beta and is not answered by this post) [Android app not creating shortcut icon on home screen (downloaded from play store)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951352/android-app-not-creating-shortcut-icon-on-home-screen-downloaded-from-play-stor)

Comment: In my experience with the beta channel, an icon isn't automatically added to the home screen but the application has been installed and is in the app drawer. This allows users to drag it from the drawer onto the home screen themselves. If the application isn't showing up in the application drawer then it is likely a ROM bug as this functionality works fine on stock Android.

Comment: This answered it, thank you Andrew. Can you copy your comment over as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience with the beta channel, an icon isn't automatically added to the home screen but the application has been installed and is in the app drawer. This allows users to drag it from the drawer onto the home screen themselves. If the application isn't showing up in the application drawer then it is likely a ROM bug as this functionality works fine on stock Android.